# Vitali Covering

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a set of finite outer measure and $F$ a collection of closed, bounded intervals that cover $E$ in the sense of Vitali. Show that there is a countable disjoint collection {${I_k}$}$_{k=1}^\infty$ of intervals in $F$ for which

$m$*$[E$~$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k] = 0$.

This is the same as the Vitali Covering Lemma except for each $\epsilon > 0$, $m$*$[E$~$\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k] < \epsilon$. In that proof, my book (Royden, 4th) uses

Theorem 11: Let $E$ be any set of real numbers. Then, each of the following four assertions is equivalent to the measurability of E.

i) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $O$ containing $E$ for which $m$*$(O$~$E)<\epsilon$.

ii) There is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ containing $E$ for which $m$*$(G$~$E)=0$.

iii), iv) etc.

Would this proof boil down to i) -> ii)?

Comment: Note that in the Vitali covering theorem $E$ need not be measurable. Also, Royden's "Vitali Covering Lemma" yields a finite collection of intervals.

Comment: From my book: The Vitali Covering Lemma - Let E be a set of finite outer measure and F a collection of closed, bounded intervals that covers E in the sense of Vitali. Then for each epsilon>0, there is a finite disjoint subcollection, Ik's, of F for which etc.

How are they different?

Comment: In the Vitali Covering Lemma, the collection of intervals obtained is finite, while in this exercise, it is countably infinite.

Note also that we only know $\mu^{*}(E)<\infty$, not necessarily that $E$ is measurable.

Comment: Ok, so what would be a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4197418/389981) for a duplicate question.

Answer (score -3):

Let E be a set of finite outer measure and :F a collection of 
closed, bounded intervals that covers E in the sense of Vitali. Then for each E > 0, there is a 
finite disjoint subcollection (Ik}k=1 of :F for which 
m* [E"- U It] < E. 
k=1 
(2) 
P

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).