# Does the union of $k$ closed balls have a name?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $k$ closed balls $B(x_i, r_i)$ with $i\in F= \{1,2,...,k\}$, is there a name for the following sets:

1. $$\bigcup_{i} B(x_i, r_i)$$
2. For $S\subset F$, the set $$\bigcap_{i\in S} B(x_i, r_i)\bigcap _{j\in F-S}\overline {B(x_j, r_j)}$$

The second region is the region in the venn diagram which is the intersection of only the balls in $S$.

I wish to use these sets a lot in my paper, but I am not sure if they have a distinct name in topology theory that I can use (instead of defining them).

Comment: As far as I know there is no special name for these sets other than what you have said, a union/intersection of balls.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific name for these kinds of sets, as is also noted in the comments.

In the situation where the balls completely contain another set of interest you can refer to them as a *covering* or *closed covering* by balls, and if the radius $r$ of the balls is significant you can talk about an $r-$covering.  Particularly relevant to this kind of covering is the [Vitali covering theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254757/vitali-covering).

I wouldn't bother inventing a new name for these notions though: rather define $B:=\cup_i B(x_i,r_i)$ and refer to $B$ thereafter.  Calling it a *cluster* or a *berry* or something else is amusing for a moment for the reader, but rapidly becomes annoying because of the need to have to keep retrieving the meaning from memory.  This is not a novel enough structure to warrant its own name, sadly.

Comment: I see, I agree that the structures of themselves are not novel to warrant a name, but they're used heavily in my algorithm that I was thinking to define them to make it simpler for myself to refer to them later on. Thank you regardless.